# Is there a way to keep parse from intercepting my notifications when using "alert" key?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, parse-platform

I am using parse to send and handle notifications for android and ios. I don't want to handle the part about sending the notification differently for either ios or android because it is not easy to determine what device or operating system a user is using. A user could have both and use the app on both ecosystems, so I want to sent out notifications which work on both android and ios.

So far I have succeeded, both device types get a notification. The thing with android and parse is, that parse is pretty stubborn. When the "alert" or the "title" key is used, then parse displays the notification before my BroadcastReceiver gets to handle it.

I did some research and to my understanding, changing the key from "alert" to something else does the trick. My problem is, I have to use "alert" no matter what to keep it working on iphones. Is there something else I could do and keep my BroadcastReceiver without parse intercepting the notification?

Is there a way to change the "alert" key and still maintain functionality under ios/iphones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to address this issue by making two different calls to Parse.Push.send() in CloudCode for iOS and Android.

```
// iOS
query.equals("deviceType", "ios");
data = {"alert":"some alert", "data":{other params here}};
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: data
}

// Android
query.equals("deviceType", "android");
data = {"data":{"alert":"some alert", other params here}, "action":"com.mycompany.customBroadcastReceiver_actionId"};
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: data
}
```

For Android, moving "alert" (and "title" if applicable) from the top level parameters to within your data params will keep Parse's PushService from intercepting the push notif and creating its own status bar notification.

You can now disable Parse's receiver and implement the notifications yourself through a custom broadcast receiver (identified by the "action" parameter). Kind of a hack, but I need custom notifs, and there doesn't seem to be another way to circumvent Parse's PushService from intercepting them if you have alert or title set.

Comment: thats what we are doing right now as well, but we are doing it in php code (php code will parse) maybe doing it in CloudCode is better